# Behavior of ctypes.CDLL attribute access

Tags: python, binding, attributes, ctypes

I am accessing a function from a DLL on Windows, although I suspect a similar interface applies on Linux. The way I normally see is to store the function object, then assign its `argtypes` and/or `restype`, and use it:

```
import ctypes
func = ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary
func.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HMODULE]
func.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL

# Call func(...)
```

Now I can use this function to unload DLLs from other sources.

But what if I set `argtypes` and `restype` directly on the attrubute of `kernel32`? Something like this:

```
dll = ctypes.windll.kernel32
dll.FreeLibrary.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HMODULE]
dll.FreeLibrary.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL

# Call dll.FreeLibrary(...)
```

I am aware that these attributes are implemented in `ctypes.CDLL` as calls to `__getitem__` (redirected from `__getattr__`). However, are the types I set this way in `argtypes`/`restype` cached, or is a fresh function reference generated every time, like with method binding?

I have not found any explicit documentation, but I do not see any tutorials using the latter method. So far, I have only been able to trace through some of the code of ctypes. The following *appears* to work, but I am not sure if it's guaranteed or a one-time coincidence:

```
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HMODULE]
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.argtypes
[ctypes.c_void_p]  # Correct alias
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
>>> ctypes.windll.kernel32.argtypes
[ctypes.c_long]    # Correct alias
```

**Note**

I understand that Windows DLL references are cached global references. This is just an example to show what happens to the method objects so readers can use a predefined object without over-complicating the MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the current implementation of [`__getattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L384) (Python 3.9), the behavior is guaranteed:

> ```
>    def __getattr__(self, name):
>        if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
>            raise AttributeError(name)
>        func = self.__getitem__(name)
>        setattr(self, name, func)
>        return func
> ```

Once `setattr` is called, the reference is stashed in `__dict__`, and future lookups will bypass `__getattr__` entirely.

This part of the code has been identical since python version 2.5: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.5/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L358. This feature does not appear to be stated explicitly anywhere in the docs.

Comment: `windll` is a cached copy shared amongst all modules, so setting attributes directly on a function in it affect other modules and can cause conflicts.  Better practice is to use `dll = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')`, then `dll.FreeLIbrary.argtypes = ...`

Comment: @MarkTolonen. That's a very good point. I was just using that for an MCVE to make sure anyone on Windows could replicate my code. Is there any reason why the method caching would not work though?

Comment: Methods are looked up once as you found, so `f = dll.func` and `g = dll.func` will be the same function reference with the same argtypes/restype.  `f is g` is `True`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen. I can see why that happens in the source, but is that a documented feature? I am pretty sure I can rely on it because it's been around forever, and the system I'm working on has pretty much nailed down the version of python